# How to pass string retrieved from stringstream by reference?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I have following function

```
void myfun(std::string &str);
```

and I'm calling this functionas follows:

```
stringstream temp("");
temp << "some string data" ;
myfun(temp.str());
```

but I'm getting following error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘myfun(std::basic_stringstream<char>::__string_type)’
```

and

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_stringstream<char>::__string_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘std::string& {aka std::basic_string<char>&}’
```

How can I pass this string by reference?

Comment: @All I need to pass it by reference to avoid creating many sting copies.

Comment: do you need to modify it? no -> use const std::string& (const lvalue reference) if you want to modify it then pass it either as is - std::string (simple copy) or through move semantics - std::string&& (rvalue reference)

Answer (score 4):

Why you need this? Why `myfun` receives reference, but not `const`? `std::stringstream::str` returns `std::string`, that is temporary object and cannot be binded to `lvalue-reference`.
You can send copy to function

```
std::string tmp = temp.str();
fun(tmp);
```

If you don't want to modify `str` in function `fun` you can rewrite it's signature to

```
void myfun(const std::string& str)
```

Comment: void myfun(const std::string& str);

Comment: void myfun(std::string&& str); as move-alternative

Answer (score 2):

`str` returns by value, i.e. a copy of the internal string in `temp`. You can't pass a copy by non-`const` reference.

You can modify the function signature to:

```
void myfun(const std::string &str);
```